# How can i display the User's name after loggin in using PHP?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I want to show the name of the user after logging in (e.g. Hey User!) using PHP, i tried the `$username = $_SESSION['username'];` but it keeps giving me nothing (Hey !).
Here's my **PHP** code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin');

mysqli_select_db($connection, 'user_registration');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$verify_emailpass = " select * from user_table where email = '$email' && password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $verify_emailpass);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  echo "Hey $username !";

}else{
  echo "<b>Incorrect Email or Password.</b>";

  }

?>
```

Here's the **Html** log in From:

```
<form action="validation.php" method="post">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-12">
      <b><p class="text-align">Se connecter:</p></b>
      </div>
    <div class="col-12">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="input-box shadow-sm" placeholder="Adresse E-mail" required/>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12">
    <input name="password" type="password" class="input-box shadow-sm" placeholder="Mot de passe" required/>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-2">
    <button id="loginButton" type="submit" class="next-button shadow-sm"><img src="res/icons/button-arrow.svg" width="45px" height="45px" /></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I was wondering how can i get any information i want from the user after he logs in in order to place it in other pages like Profile page or so?

Comment: Is the variable `$username` being set in the first place?

Comment: no i'm looking for a way to get it from where the email and password locate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If this page is login than session is empty

I think it's check mysql email and password
Than this code

```
$data['username']
```

username is mysql name column name

````
<?php

session_start();

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin');

mysqli_select_db($connection, 'user_registration');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$verify_emailpass = " select * from user_table where email = '$email' && password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $verify_emailpass);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
$data =  $result->fetch_assoc()
$_SESSION['username'] = $data['username'];
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  echo "Hey $username !";

}else{
  echo "<b>Incorrect Email or Password.</b>";

  }

?>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Update this line with

> $username = $_SESSION['username'];

With this

> $username = $result[‘username’];   $_SESSION['username'] =
> $username;